# Making simple api calls to YouTube v3 api

Tags: javascript, php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I made some projects a while ago that were on the v2 api.

As such they are now dead.

I am wanting to fix them, but there is a lot of code relying on the YT api in my projects.
As such, I am wanting the simplest way to make the calls.

An example is this code that used to work.

```
<?php
$realUserName = 'Google'; ///////     YouTube username
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $realUserName . '?v=2&alt=json');

$data = json_decode($data, true);
$stats_data = $data['entry']['yt$statistics'];   

echo 'lastWebAccess = '.$stats_data['lastWebAccess'].'<br />';
echo 'published = '.$data['entry']['published']['$t'].'<br />'; 
echo 'subscriberCount = '.$stats_data['subscriberCount'].'<br />';
echo 'viewCount = '.$stats_data['viewCount'].'<br />';
echo 'totalUploadViews = '.$stats_data['totalUploadViews'].'<br />';
echo 'userId = '. $data['entry']['yt$userId']['$t'].'<br />';
echo 'channelId = '.$data['entry']['yt$channelId']['$t'].'<br />'; 
echo 'username = '. $data['entry']['yt$username']['$t'].'<br />';
echo 'title = '.$data['entry']['title']['$t'].'<br />';     
echo 'displayname = '. $data['entry']['yt$username']['display'].'<br /><br /><br />';
echo 'location = '.$data['entry']['yt$location']['$t'].'<br />';      
?>
```

I am basically looking for options that are not relying on outside plugins or downloaded lib's that will bloat my projects even more than needed.

I was already using outh2 for some things, so that side is understandable.

Or is it now no option but to use the "extra" library's from google with the long winded coding?

Comment: This code is very long winded, so I wouldnt worry about googles long winded code.  Just download the best library you can find, computers are fast enough these days for you to not have to worry much about bloat.

Comment: @Toby Allen . The "echo" part is streamline able for sure ;p. But looking at google examples, they are long winded to do the same job. Too much of a headache.

Comment: You can try using the [libraries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries), which are available for many programming languages, can greatly simplify your YouTube API implementation. Since you are using OAuth 2.0, requesting to the API with authentication would be easy as YouTube Data API supports the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authorizing access to private user data. Hope this helps.